# AuthError On YouTube Search List Execute

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I am exploring YouTube API and creating a java application which can search with authorized users token. I do Authorization as follows.

```
private static Credential authorize(String storeDirectory) throws Exception {
    // load client secrets

    YT.DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(".",".store/"+storeDirectory);
    YT.dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(YT.DATA_STORE_DIR);

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(YT.JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(YT.CLIENT_SECRET_JSON.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus "
          + "into client string.");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    String[] permissoins = { PlusScopes.PLUS_LOGIN, PlusScopes.PLUS_ME, PlusScopes.USERINFO_EMAIL, PlusScopes.USERINFO_PROFILE, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" };
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        YT.httpTransport, YT.JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(permissoins))).setDataStoreFactory(
        YT.dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
}
```

I am trying to search a single keyword as bellow

```
Credential credential = authorize("username");
YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");
// I have set OauthToken here. 
search.setOauthToken(credential.getAccessToken());
search.setMaxResults(50L);
search.setQ("Search keyword");
search.setType("video");
search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
// It get exception below line.
SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
```

I am getting exception details as below.

```
ex = (com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException) com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

I am wondering i am missing to set any api key or I do something else wrong.

Do i need to use

`search.setKey("YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY");`

I am also confused what to use as `YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY` ?

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java) and the [OAuth documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) if you haven't done so already. What happens when you use your API key for the `YOUTUBE_DEVELOPER_KEY`?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try this: https://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/gwt/index.html#settings

Comment: @not_a_bot I tried with developer key generated with above link but no luck.

Comment: Do you have the APIs enabled in the developer console?

Comment: Yes, I have already enabled YouTube Data API, Youtube Analytic and Freebased API. Previously I didn't have added permission for YouTube while OAuth authorization, but i have added that permission after in scope. I notice that if i use other youtube account my source code working fine. But not working with my account. I really appreciate your effort to help me and Thank for your time. If the scenario not clear to you let me know. I will explain it.